# How to check availble package software versions in AWS SSH?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, ssh, version-control

I wanted to install the following packages in my EC2 instances via SSH

```
sudo yum install gcc make httpd php-common php cli php-pear php-devel git ImageMagick-devel
```

But I would like to know, is it possible to get the list of available versions of the each package before I install?

```
eg:
PHP:4x
PHP:5x

php-pear xV
```

like wise for each software packages?

Comment: Are you using amazon linux? If so, php 5.3 uses the `php` prefix, 5.4 uses php54, and so on up to 5.6. You can run different versions side by side and switch using alternatives.

Comment: yes I use amazon linux, I can easily understand the PHP version but what about other packages?

Comment: Some packages are versioned to run side by side, like ruby, php, java, and python. For everything else you can get the package version by doing  `yum list <package>`